# alert other threads of event/action

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a server/client application that uses a number of threads to handle various aspects of the system. A new thread is created in a `ClientHandler` object that manages communications between the server and a client, every time a new client connects to the server.
A separate thread functions as a countdown clock to a `Calendar` object that begins when the server is started, and it is here that I would like some kind of inter-thread communication.

This is the code that detects when the deadline has passed:

```
    //Retrieve current date and time...
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    //deadline not yet reached
    while(now.before(deadline))
    {
        try
        {
            //wait a second and try again
            sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException intEx)
        {
            intEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Update current date and time...
        now = Calendar.getInstance();
        //run loop again
    }
```

Immediately after this loop has finished, I would like to somehow inform the other threads that the deadline has been reached.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to do this. In other parts of my program I have used `Socket`s and `Scanner/PrintWriter` for input and output. That would probably be possible here but seems a fairly convoluted way of doing things.

I did some research and saw Java methods `wait()` and `notify()` were commonly used. Would they be at all possible to accomplish what I am after? If not, is there a better way than those I've already mentioned?

Comment: How about using the Observer pattern to notify subscribers, which in this case would be other threads?

Comment: Hi, I'm relatively new to Java so I'm not familiar with this functionality. Would you mind elaborating? @WillyduPreez

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the Observer pattern. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to implement distributed event handling systems.

Other threads would then subscribe to your timer thread. When the deadline is reached, the timer thread can notify the other threads that the deadline has been reached.

As an example, in your Timer class you would have a method:

```
 public void subscribe(DeadlineListener listener) {
     this.subscribers.add(listener); // subscribers is a List
 }
```

Then the deadline listener interface would look be something along the following lines:

```
 public interface DeadlineListener {
      public void onDeadlineReached();
 }
```

In your Timer's run method once the deadline has been reached, you can then notify subcribers:

```
 // Deadline has been reached
 for (DeadlineListener listener : subcsribers) {
      listener.onDeadlineReached();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Whilst the observer pattern may be fine as a higher-level abstraction, the simple mechanism shown here does not get round the somewhat-basic issue that threads cannot be called, either directly or through a list of event interfaces.

Comment: The event-handlers, though they may be members of other class instances, will be called in the context of the firing thread and would require further 'real' inter-thread comms to signal their target thread.   I'm not saying that its' a bad design, (it's actually quite good since it encapsulates the inter-thread comms into the target thread instances, where it belongs), just that it's more complex than you describe.

Comment: @MartinJames, I agree, the above design is simplistic and is intended only to get the idea of the pattern across. The implementation of onDeadlineReached() will have to handle the 'real' inter-thread communication (which will be to get the notified thread to act on the notification within it's own run() method).